# Scala checking whether a key exists in an array

Tags: scala, playframework

Here is my code:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.tuple
import play.api.data.Forms.text


object Application extends Controller {

def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}

val form = Form(
tuple(
  "name" -> text,
  "address" -> text,
  "x_card_num" -> text
 )
)

def payment = Action { implicit request =>
  def values = form.bindFromRequest.data
  def name = values("name")

  //val card_num = ""
  //values.isDefinedAt("x_card_num")
  if (values.get("x_card_num") == None)       {
      val card_num = "test"
  }   else    {
    //def card_num = values("x_card_num")
    val card_num = "test2"
}

//val card_num = "test"
Ok(views.html.payment("testing",name,card_num))
}

}
```

It doesn't work. It just to totally skips over the if (values.get("x_card_num") == None) and else statement, and card_num ends up as an empty string, as defined before the if else statement.

Why would it totally ignore the if else statement?

And how do I check to see whether the key exists in the array "values"?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to try and reduce your "problem" down to some minimal example. In your case, the play stuff is completely extraneous

Comment: This is the second time you ask almost the same questions, that can be considered as basic knowledge. Please read a book about scala first and if you face any problems you can still ask. Here's the free online version of `Programming in Scala`: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/a-scalable-language.html

Comment: `values` is not an array. Arrays do not have keys.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are *shadowing* the outer scope. That is, you are declaring **more than one** value called `card_num`.

```
if (values.get("x_card_num") == None) {     
   val card_num = "test"   
// ^^^
// this is a new variable declaration in a different scope
} 
else  
  val card_num = "test2"
```

In scala, *everything is an expression*, so you can simply do this:

```
val card_num = if (values.get("x_card_num") == None)  "test" else { ... }
```

That is, the *if-block* itself evaluates to a value (as long as there is an `else`)

the other option is to use *variables* as opposed to *values*, but this is not idiomatic (you should avoid `var`s):

```
var card_num = null
if ( .. ) 
   card_num = "test"
// ^^^
// Notice no val or var here
```

---

You could use `isDefinedAt` to simplify the test

```
val cardNum = if (values isDefinedAt "x_card_num") "test2" else "test"
```